# Deleted Table View Cell Copying Remaining Tableview Cell Instead of Disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've got a UITableView that pulls some information from a Firebase Realtime Database. The information all gets pulled and populated properly, and deletes when it is supposed to, but I get a weird bug. If there are multiple cells in the table view, when I delete one of the cells, instead of that cell disappearing, it just gets replaced with a copy of one of the remaining cells. When I then close the table view and reopen it, everything is correct (i.e. the copied cell is gone). I have included some photos of this below as an illustration. Here is the swift file for the table view:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class SpotRemove: ViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var tblSpots: UITableView!
    
    var spotsList = [ArtistModel]()
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return spotsList.count
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        
        let spot: ArtistModel
        
        spot = spotsList[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.lblName.text = spot.type
        cell.lblGenre.text = spot.avail
        cell.lblPrice.text = spot.price
        
        return cell
    }
    
    var refSpots: DatabaseReference?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblSpots.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        refSpots = Database.database().reference().child("Spots")
        refSpots?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                for spots in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                    let spotKey = spots.key
                    let spotObject = spots.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let spotType = spotObject?["Type"]
                    let spotAvail = spotObject?["Availability"]
                    let spotPrice = spotObject?["Price"]
                    let spotID = spotObject?["UserID"]
                    
                    
                    let spot = ArtistModel(id: spotID as! String?, avail: spotAvail as! String?, type: spotType as! String?, price: spotPrice as! String?, key: spotKey as! String?)
                    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                    if userID == spotID as? String {
                    self.spotsList.append(spot)
                    }
                }
                self.tblSpots.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let spot = self.spotsList[indexPath.row]
        
        if let spotKey = spot.key {
            Database.database().reference().child("Spots").child(spotKey).removeValue { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Failed to delete message:", error!)
                    return
                }
                self.spotsList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tblSpots.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.tblSpots.reloadData()
            }
            tblSpots.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is that I'm calling reloadData() without changing numberOfRowsInSection. Would the fix be as simple as putting something like numberOfRowsInSection = numberOfRowsInSection - 1 right before I call reload data? Thank you all in advance.

[the two original cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0xH0.png)

[the two cells after deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd0UO.png)

[The reloaded table view showing only the remaining cell (as it is supposed to)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpPYI.png)

Comment: **Never** call `reloadData` right after `deleteRows`. Delete the line. `insert/delete/moveRows` does update the UI. And delete the second occurrence of `reloadData`in the method, too. It has no effect.

Comment: So if I remove those two instances of reloadData it should work? Or should I still put in something like numberOfRowsInSection - 1?

Comment: No, just delete both occurrences of `reloadData()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now.

Comment: I have removed those two instances of reloadData(), but that does not change anything on the user end.

Answer (score 0):

It's a round-about, brute force way, but I decided to have the array and the table view clear all contents then reload them from scratch. This works (but is not perfect for optimizing efficiency). The whole delete function now looks like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let spot = self.spotsList[indexPath.row]
        
        if let spotKey = spot.key {
            Database.database().reference().child("Spots").child(spotKey).removeValue { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Failed to delete message:", error!)
                    return
                }
                self.spotsList.removeAll()
                self.tblSpots.reloadData()
                
                self.refSpots = Database.database().reference().child("Spots")
                self.refSpots?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                        for spots in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                            let spotKey = spots.key
                            let spotObject = spots.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                            let spotType = spotObject?["Type"]
                            let spotAvail = spotObject?["Availability"]
                            let spotPrice = spotObject?["Price"]
                            let spotID = spotObject?["UserID"]
                            
                            
                            let spot = ArtistModel(id: spotID as! String?, avail: spotAvail as! String?, type: spotType as! String?, price: spotPrice as! String?, key: spotKey as! String?)
                            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                            if userID == spotID as? String {
                            self.spotsList.append(spot)
                            }
                        }
                        self.tblSpots.reloadData()
                    }
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
```